# Extract national boundaries from file

Tags: coordinates, extract, boundaries

I would like to know how to extract national boundaries coordinates into a text file.

I've downloaded some files from natural earth (like shapefile, json etc..) but I don't know how to use them.

My aim is to extract wgs84 national border coordinates from those files (Italy) and put them into another program (housemade) that can read those coordinates and draw them as an image (shape to be precise).

How can I do this?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Where are the national boundaries from?

Comment: @Pointdump qgis. But I don't know how to use it

Comment: @Mapperz Italy boundaries

Comment: What language are you using in your own program?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a number of ways, depending on what exactly you downloaded and what software are already installed on your system. Assuming you have no special software already, I'd recommend some online conversion site like https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-geojson (I've never used it, just found on Google). With [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) (see also: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON)), you should be able to read the `"geometry"` property to extract a list of `[longitude, latitude]` pairs. I'm going to guess Italy will be a MultiPolygon geometry, so the geojson geometry will be a list of lists of coordinates.

It might not matter to you, but if you draw these WGS84 coords as x,y coordinates in an image, etc, they'll probably look "weird" compared to what you normally see on web maps like Google Maps, which uses Web Mercator. That's because the WGS84 coordinates are not projected onto a plane like Web Mercator.

*Edit to add more detail for qgis specifically.*

For qgis, right click your shapefile and export.
[image]

Choose one of the two geojson types.
[image]

The exported file will have a bunch of json in it, something like in the following picture. But obviously your data is different than my example.
[image]

After that, parse the json using your favorite programming language or even just a text editor. It's dead simple. Read the links above about geojson, especially the link to wikipedia, to understand the structure of the format. Geojson is nothing special, just json in a particular format or structure. As I've already said, the longitude and latitude coordinate pairs will be in a `"geometry"` field of (one of) the json object(s).

Comment: Thanks. Currently I'm usin qgis but it's quite complicated and I don't know how to use it. Can yoy be more specific?